# Isn't cosine an even function?

Tags: power

I changed the question as I was not clear.

Is the following true?

**cos(+ωt-π/2) = cos(-ωt-π/2)**

No, as I tried random angles for ωt as shown below

[image]

So, yes Cosine is an even function but the whole angle should be negated and not only the phase shift part right?

Comment: no, it's not correct, as the test demonstrates. Hint: try out different values for \$\omega t\$ and see how you're wrong.

Comment: This is a confusing question, but it seems like the answer is yes? if x=wt+pi/2, and cos(-x)=cos(x), then cos(-wt-pi/2)=cos(wt+pi/2). This question could probably be worded better though (and when i say question here, i mean this stackexchange question, not the exam question)

Comment: @MarcusMüller if wt=pi/2, then wt+pi/2 = pi, and -wt-pi/2 = -pi, and cos(pi)=cos(-pi)

Comment: @BeB00 yes, but for \$\omega t\ne n\pi,\,n\in\mathbb N\$, this doesn't hold. You just hand-picked values that worked.

Comment: @OMAR if your question was actually "is the book wrong?" then the answer is no. This isnt what you asked though, so youll have to clarify it

Comment: @MarcusMüller Are you sure? cos(3+pi/2) is equal to cos(-3-pi/2) (the result is -0.14112000806)

Comment: Not really an electrical engineering question, but a simple math question. No offense to the OP, but down voting because it is somewhat off topic.

Comment: @BeB00 aah you're right

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is more a generic Math problem than something related to electronics design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your new question is **no**.

You made a sign mistake, thinking that -(wt+π/2)=(wt+π/2), which is incorrect.

The answer to the question you originally asked, which is basically:

> does cos(-wt-π/2) = cos(wt+π/2)

is yes.